# why timezone like '+00:00' ignored with select but error with create table?

Tags: mariadb, mariadb-10.3

I am wondering, why does mariadb ignore timezone like '+00:00' with select statement however throw the error with create table statement?

```
SELECT CAST('2020-07-09 09:55:36.933554+00:00' AS DATE) dt;

# dt 
2020-07-09

CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE tmp AS 
SELECT CAST('2020-07-09 09:55:36.933554+00:00' AS DATE) dt;

# (1292): Truncated incorrect datetime value: '2020-07-09 09:55:36.933554+00:00'
```

I read [the question](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/48704/mysql-5-6-datetime-incorrect-datetime-value-2013-08-25t1700000000-with-er) about the error and understand how to fix it. Just curious why such not obvious for me behaviour.

- mariadb 10.3.15

Comment: the code that interprets the select is another than the one from the create, in mysql it does the same, so it gives no error, but mariadb hasn't fixed the issue or it doesn't think that it is a bug. It still doesn't work in 10.5

Comment: @nbk thanks for your reply! could you please provide any link related the bug if it's possible?